# Spring Boot: How to create a Progress Bar in Spring Boot and Thymeleaf with Ajax?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to create and update a progress bar in the webpage. I have a Controller generating values that needs to be updated in the progress bar. I am using concept of Ajax to get the values from the controller but not being successful on that.

Controller: Basically, I am downloading a file from the internet. The onDownloading() is generating value that needs to be passed to the progress bar.

I am using Ajax.

I tried using ResponseBodyEmitter emitter.send() but didn't work as expected. I want one value at a time until the download is finished but ResponseBodyEmitter is giving me all the values at once in the end when the download is finished.

Right now my code in Controller when the form is submitted to download the video.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/videoTest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String downloadVideo(){
        File downloadFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads");
        try {
            video = downloader.getVideo("123456789");
            VideoFormat vFormat = video.findVideoWithQuality(VideoQuality.valueOf("medium")).get(0);
            video.downloadAsync(vFormat, downloadFile, "title", new OnYoutubeDownloadListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDownloading(int i) {
                    gValue = false;
                    getValue = i;


                    System.out.println("Video: " + i);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinished(File file) {
//                    gValue = true;
                    System.out.println("Download Video Complete.");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

                }
            });
        } catch (IOException | YoutubeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

I want to get the value of  from onDownloading(int i) to be updated in progress bar.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add more code to better understand the problem?

Comment: @Wim Deblauwe Hi.. I have added my Controller code. Please let me know if you have any questions to solve the problem. Thanks.